# How can I use ThreeJS ES6 native modules with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, three.js, es6-modules

I am using ThreeJS ES6 native modules directly in the browser. It's a really cool feature where you can just `import` ThreeJS from your javascript files without any module bundler.

The following works in javascript:

```
import * as THREE from './lib/three.module.js'
import { OrbitControls } from './lib/OrbitControls.js'
```

Now I want to do this in Typescript, I installed the typescript definitions using

```
npm install --save @types/three
```

But VS Code still can't find the type declaration files:

`⚠️ Could not find a declaration file for module '../lib/three.module.js'`

`⚠️  Could not find a declaration file for module '../lib/OrbitControls.js'.`

As suggested in the comments I changed the imports to

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'
```

Now the declarations are found, but typescript can't find the modules!

`⚠️  An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context and Failed to resolve module specifier "three".`

`⚠️  Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

How can I use ES6 native modules from ThreeJs in my Typescript project without a module bundler?

Answer (score 2):

Try to organize your imports like so:

```js
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
```

Comment: Thanks, now type checking works, but when compiling I get: `An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context` and `Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using?

Comment: Version 3.4.5. After lots of trial and error, I couldn't get native modules working with typescript compilation. So now I just installed `npm install three` and use a module bundler. This works. I still don't know if native modules can work with typescript though.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to create a `.d.ts` file with the same name as the library -- in your case, `./lib/three.module.d.ts`.  When you `import * as Three from "./lib/three.module.js"`, Typescript will look for a sibling typings file as part of the module resolution strategy.  In this file, you can simply `export` types that describe the shape of the module.  In your case, you should be fine with just

```
import * as Three from "three";
export = Three;
```

Comment: hm this seems promising! The `.d.ts` file didn't seem to get picked up right away, but maybe I did something wrong. Will fuss with it a bit later :)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution from Jamesernator over at the TypeScript Github Issues: just add this to your html:

```
<script type="importmap">
            {
                "imports": {
                    "three": "./js/lib/three.module.js"
                 }
            }    
 </script>
```

And the browser will do the remapping. Neat!

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50600

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you have to use an alias for declaration files, and aliases are not supported by es6 native import statements.  This is not addressed at all in the docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html

Some people resolve this by adding a whole honkin build pipeline, but that level of complexity was not for me: [Typescript declaration file created with alias instead of relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52500365/typescript-declaration-file-created-with-alias-instead-of-relative-path)

Instead I used tsc-watch and a minimal bash script: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-watch

`$ tsc-watch --onSuccess "./mysed"`

```
$ cat ./mysed
#!/bin/bash

# use *js to capture .mts as well as .js
sed -i "" "s/import \* as THREE from 'three';/import \* as THREE from '.\/lib\/three\.module\.js';/" js/*js;
```

This replaces `import * as THREE from 'three';` in my .ts with `import * as THREE from './lib/three.module.js'` in my JS, allowing me to reference the typed version in dev and the non typed version in prod.  Whew!