# Rollup & Typescript type declarations with absolute imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rollup

I'm making React component library. Project structure is something like:

```
src/
   components/
   utils/
   hooks/
```

Now I'm trying to generate types (.d.ts.) files using rollup. Types are generated but e.g. my component `NumberInput` is using absolute import from `Input` component like so:

```
import Input from "components/Input/Input";
```

Now imports in `NumberInput.d.ts` look exactly the same:

```
import Input from "components/Input/Input";
```

But now those imports in `d.ts` files are not gonna be resolved since there is no tsconfig.json for generated code (I Guess).

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": "src/",
    "paths": {
      "components/*": ["components/*"],
      "models/*": ["hooks/*"],
      "utils/*": ["utils/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build", "dist", "scripts", "acceptance-tests", "webpack", "jest"],
  "types": ["typePatches"]
}
```

**rollup.config.js**

```
export default {
  input: [
    "./src/index.ts",
    ...getFiles("./src/components", extensions),
    ...getFiles("./src/hooks", extensions),
    ...getFiles("./src/utils", extensions)
  ],
  output: [
    {
      dir: "dist",
      format: "esm",
      sourcemap: true
    }
  ],
  external: ["react", "react-dom", "styled-components"],
  plugins: [
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    typescript({
      tsconfig: "./tsconfig.build.json",
      declaration: true,
      declarationDir: "dist"
    }),
    image(),
    url({
      include: ["**/*.woff2"],
      limit: Infinity
    }),
    css(),
    terser()
  ],
  external: ["react", "react-dom", "styled-components"]
};
```

Is there any way I can control absolute imports when types are being generated? I wanna use absolute imports inside my project, but when types are generated I rly don't care how they look as long as they work.

Comment: use @zerollup/ts-transform-paths plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zerollup/ts-transform-paths

Comment: @marko-radoš did you manage to solve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

The best working solution imo is nicely summed up in this [article](https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/typescript-library-tips-rollup-your-types-995153cc81c7) by using [rollup-plugin-dts](https://github.com/Swatinem/rollup-plugin-dts).

In plugin you can pass `compilerOptions` parameter, with `basePath` and `paths` so it will correctly resolve absolute imports of type declarations.
`rollup.config.ts` file:

```js
...
 plugins: [
      dts({
        compilerOptions: {
          baseUrl: tsConfig.compilerOptions.baseUrl,
          paths: tsConfig.compilerOptions.paths,
        },
      }),
    ],
...
```

Comment: I was struggling on that issue for a time, you answer helped me a lot, thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

You have told typescript for files, but rollup does not know how to actually resolve rollup will look in home folder if you write `components/a.ts`

There is a plugin for rollup [@rollup/plugin-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-alias)

```
plugins: [
    alias({
      entries: [
        { find: 'components', replacement: 'your path to components folder' },
      ]
    })
  ]
```

**EDIT**
[image]

Comment: ty for quick response! I tried this but it doesn't seem to be working, nothing changes. `{ find: "components", replacement: "../../components" }`

Comment: Yep, everything is as per docs for me, but imports do not change in .d.ts declaration files that are being generated. So when I use my lib it throws few errors in console saying that it can't find `components` and `utils` directory since absolute paths are still being used.